# (TFS) Test Result meaning of field "Tested Build"

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops-server-2019

I am working with Azure DevOps Server (TFS) Test Management tool but there is a field concerning Test Results that I can find anywhere in docs for explanation.

[image]

The field is named **Tested Build**, I've attached an image highlighting it.
If one can give maximum details about it, it would be great. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tested Build` is the build number when this test run is produced from a pipeline. For example, if you use `Visual Studio Test` task to run tests in a pipeline, you'll see the `Tested Build` shows the build number.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Cece and sorry for the late